# Modify Web Page Content in Safari 12?

Tags: safari, safari-extensions

The tool I was using to block `#hot-network-questions` is now blocked in Safari 12.

I can see some ad blockers are still allowed, but I cannot find one which allows custom blocking specific content.

Can anyone recommend a way to block specific content in the new Safari 12 world?

Answer (score 1):

[AdBlock](https://getadblock.com) still works - better than the newer App Store version - on Mojave & Safari 12.

You can simply drag a box round content you want rid of & then shift a slider until you're happy, then Click Done.
I use it on SE to remove the Watched & Ignored Tags sections, as well as standard ads.

Comment: Thanks for this. I can't find anywhere on the site to find the non MAS version? And the MAS version doesn't appear to have the feature you mention. :(

Comment: Ahh, sorry - web page looks the same, but the link is now only to the App Store. I hadn't realised. I guess you need to already have it, or find it elsewhere [probably not recommended]